# template repeat in a polymer html

Tags: html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I got this piece of code:

```
<template repeat="{{ name in data }}">
        <style>
        </style>
                <li>
                    <input data-index="{{ id }}" type="{{ type }}" name="name" value="{{ value }}" >
                    {{data.name}}
                </li>
    </template>
```

But the loop is not working, actually. Only the last element of the array has been printed...

It's polymer 1.0...

any ideas?

thank you :D

Answer (score 1):

Looks like code from old Polymer (`0.5` or similar)

```
<style>
</style>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data }}" as="name"> 
   <li>
      <input data-index="{{ id }}" type="{{ type }}" name="name" value="{{ value }}" >
        {{data.name}}
  </li>
</template>
```

`as="name"` is optional, default is `item`

see also https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates.html

Comment: the last element disappeared as well...got a blank page =/

Comment: Hard to tell. You code is only a disconnected fragment. I don't know what `data`, `id`, `type`, `value` is supposed to look like or where it comes from.

Comment: If I put a second template tag, nothing works in that tag. If I put the 'dom-repeat' thing in the first template tag, I got a blank page, nothing works as well.

Comment: The link at the bottom of my answer has a nice example that shows how to use it.